# different column from radio button in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

)

im quite new to R and also Shiny, but let me explain my current problem.

I have a csv file that looks like this:

| Week | First | Second | Third |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 22 | 33 |
| 2 | 44 | 55 | 66 |
| 3 | 77 | 88 | 99 |

I allrdy created a line chart that shows me on the x-line the "Week" and on the y-line the column "First".
i also implemented that i can access the range between the weeks, so that I can choose what Data i want to see (f.E only week 2 - 3 or 1 - 2)

What im now trying to do now is the following,
Ive set up some radio buttons...

```
radioButtons("typeInput", "Choose",
              choices = c("First", "Second", "Third"),
              selected = "First"))
```

And Im trying to make it interactive, so that when I choose Radiobutton "Second" i want to see the data from the column "second" on the line chart compared to the column "Week" which will be selected at all time

This is my Server Code so far:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
output$PLOT <- renderPlot({
    filtered <-
      Data %>%
      filter(week>= input$Weekinput[1],
             week<= input$Weekinput[2]
      )
    ggplot(filtered, aes(week, First)) +
      geom_line()
  })
}
```

Does anyone has an Idea how I can get to this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `input$typeInput` to get the selected value from radiobutton.

```
output$PLOT <- renderPlot({
  filtered <-
    Data %>%
    filter(week>= input$Weekinput[1],
           week<= input$Weekinput[2]
    )
  ggplot(filtered, aes(week, .data[[input$typeInput]])) +
    geom_line()
})
```

Comment: I've tried to put "input$typeInput" to the y-line but i didnt work...
Now im trying to figure out what the ".data" is about and then I should be good to go.

Thanks a Lot!!!! :-)

Comment: `.data` pronoun is used when you are passing string column names like here. `input$typeInput` is a string value.